# how to enable dvcapture through firewire (ieee1394)

Tags: video, firewire

Newbie here...
Ubuntu 19.1 Studio user & installed very recently (multiboot win10)
Can't seem to get dv-capture working via the firewirecard
(i have around a 100 mini-dv-tapes which i would like to capture in the native dv-format)

Kdenlive doesn't seem to suppport the ancient mini-dv-format,
so i installed Kino but kino doesn't recognize any capture device or camera 
Below i posted the Hardware-info-dump, which clearly shows the firewire-card being detected
(Texas Instruments TSB12LV23 IEEE-1394 Controller)

Visited many fora/threads to try and find a solution,
but besides that they are of several years ago,
no one seems to have found a solution...

So how can i get dv-capture working ?
Anyone ?

I have done this in terminal:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf
```

( to rem all this: blacklist ohci1394 , blacklist sbp2 , blacklist dv1394 , blacklist raw1394 , blacklist video1394 , blacklist firewire-ohci , blacklist firewire-sbp2 )

---

also i added this: `https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libraw1394-dev_2.1.2-1_amd64.deb.html`

Install Howto:
Update the package index:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get update
Install libraw1394-dev deb package:
$ sudo apt-get install libraw1394-dev
```

---

also done in terminal:

```bsh
$ hwinfo --short
cpu: 
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6700 @ 2.66GHz, 2541 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6700 @ 2.66GHz, 2566 MHz

keyboard:
/dev/input/event2 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard

mouse:
/dev/input/mice ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse

monitor:
IIYAMA ProLiteH430

graphics card:
Hightech Information Caicos [Radeon HD 5450]

sound:
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series]

storage:
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode]

network:
enp2s8 Intel NM10/ICH7 Family LAN Controller

network interface:
enp2s8 Ethernet network interface
lo Loopback network interface

disk:
/dev/sdf Generic SD/MMC
/dev/sdd Generic Compact Flash
/dev/sdb ST3250310AS
/dev/sdg Generic MS/MS-Pro
/dev/sde Generic SM/xD-Picture
/dev/sdc TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
/dev/sda M4-CT064M4SSD2

partition:
/dev/sdb1 Partition
/dev/sdb2 Partition
/dev/sdb5 Partition
/dev/sdc1 Partition
/dev/sda1 Partition
/dev/sda2 Partition

cdrom:
/dev/sr0 HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GSA-H60L

usb controller:
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller

bios:
BIOS

bridge:
Intel 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge
Intel 82946GZ/PL/GL PCI Express Root Port
Intel 82801 PCI Bridge
Intel 82946GZ/PL/GL Memory Controller Hub

hub:
Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

memory:
Main Memory

firewire controller:
Texas Instruments TSB12LV23 IEEE-1394 Controller

unknown:
FPU
DMA controller
PIC
Keyboard controller
Intel NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller
```